# Camera for Couple and Event Photography

Tags: lens, nikon, photoshop, event-photography

I have Nikon D5300 camera with two lenses ( 18-55mm  f/3.5-5.6G & 55-200mm f/4-5.6G), please let me know if my camera and lenses work for Couple and Event Photography? if not , what Camera and Lens do you recommend ?

Comment: Gear is rarely an issue. If you're learning, that's a fine setup. If you're trying to be a pro and charge for your work...well, I don't think you're at that point yet (a pro knows when their kit isn't going to suit a job). That being said, welcome to the site, and please **do** post any questions you have along the way as you learn to shoot portraits and events. Also - you should pick up a speedlight - they're invaluable in dark event spaces.

Comment: Voting to close this question as too broad. If there's a specific type of shot or "look" that you're going for...post more specifics and then this question will no longer be "too broad".

Comment: Event photography : get a good flash and learn to use it.  I suspect from the question that your general photography technique is also in need of learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Those work fine. However, they probably aren't *sufficient*. It is likely you will need more than that — you'll need lighting, and more than that, you will need some skill with the subject, and, frankly, one way you will know if you are ready for that is when you stop worrying about whether your camera and lens are good enough for it.